# Selecing an item in a Blackberry ListField

Tags: java, blackberry, menu, smartphone, listfield

I've been using this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849690200) as reference to creating my Blackberry application. So far I have a list of items and when I select one I get the side menu but next to my list item:

[image]

Just looking through my methods, I'm not sure which one causes this as I can remove the custom item (GetValue) from the Menu and it will still appear here when I select the list item!

I guess my question is, how can I stop this menu appearing and have a method fire instead? I can provide code if necessary but I don't know where to start with this one!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you show your code when invoking the method.

When I override the navigationClick method of the ListField class like in the code below it works properly. (no menu pops)

```
protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time){
    return true;
```

}

Comment: Hey I was playing about this earlier and got it to work! I read that if you don't do anything it automatically draws the menu. Will post the code tomorrow. I still have an issue that it doesn't work on phones with keyboards (I think).

Answer (score 2):

@ing0

You can override default menu by using OnMenu() method

public boolean onMenu(int i)

{

```
    return false;

}
```

Comment: Hey, I want the menu to appear when pressing the menu button but not when I select the list item! Know how to do that?